# Authentic (non-touristic) places, where Italians eat, in Verona and Venezia

Tags: italy, price, restaurants

I don't like very touristic places, and I don't care about the international renown of a restaurant. I do care about their local renown, since I enjoy to be among the locals. (For instance, I like becoming my menu in without translation, sign that tourists don't discover that place so easily; but that's dispensable).

Accordingly, I'd like somebody to recommend me a place to eat in Venice and Verona, local traditional dishes (preferentially affordable, but if it's quite good food, it doesn't matter). I'll be there in May (in case it's relevant).

Comment: You can check out the Ristorante Cuore Antico in Verona. "Discovered" about 10 years ago and we turned it in to a Christmas dinner tradition.  In Venice, it's strictly La Caravella, it's a bit pricey and perhaps borderline 'touristy' so maybe it doesn't count.